# Unassigned shards of the index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have unassigned shards in my ElasticSearch cluster and I don't know how to fix it. I have removed the index and created it again, but the picture ist the same.

[image]

How to fix it?

--- Edit ----

```
{
  "cluster_name": "node_name",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
  "active_primary_shards": 8,
  "active_shards": 12,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 4,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 75
}
```

Comment: What kind of shards? how many nodes are you running? What have you tried? Have you looked into the _cat API?

Comment: 2 nodes, 8 shards. I have many times removed the index and generate it again, but become ever the same picture above. What is _cat API?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html  Have you looked in /var/log/elasticsearch/{{cluster_name}}.log? What version of Elastic are you using?

Comment: It's not an uncommon problem btw. If you google around for unallocated shards in Elastic, odds are good you'll find what you need. BTW, version can play a big factor here. Pre ES 1.6 or so it was pretty common to see this. These days not so much.

Comment: I have yesterday updated to the last version. Ok some solution to make this shards active?

Comment: Provide the output of `GET /_recovery` and `GET /_cat/shards`. Also, the log file would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! There were 2 different versions of the nodes 2.3.1 and 2.2.0. Because I have update ElasticSearch with the current version yesterday, the second node should I update manually, because it is on the same server. Because the different versions, there were this unassgned shards.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Below is a bash which could force the fix (change the server name to your target node's):

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(curl -s 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards' | fgrep UNASSIGNED); do
  INDEX=$(echo $line | (awk '{print $1}'))
  SHARD=$(echo $line | (awk '{print $2}'))

  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
     "commands": [
        {
            "allocate": {
                "index": "'$INDEX'",
                "shard": '$SHARD',
                "node": "SERVER_NAME_OF_THE TARGET_NODE",
                "allow_primary": true
            }
        }
     ]
  }'
```